# Python Social Auth Pipeline not working

Tags: python, django, facebook

This is my code for fetching user details using python social auth. Once the user is authenticated from Facebook, and facebook re-directs back to my custom URL, my application is not being able to log the user in.

If I remove the below code, then everything works smoothly (i.e. user can log in) but I am not able to fetch extra details from Facebook. I need to fetch Date of Birth and Address from Facebook along with other default details.

Any help with fetching details from Google would be appreciated. I could not find any documentation to fetch details from Google.

```
def get_profile_data(backend, details, response, social_user, uid, user, *args, **kwargs):
profile= Profile.objects.get_or_create(user=user)
if backend.__class__.__name__ == 'FacebookOAuth2':

    if not user.email and response.get('email'):
        user.email = response.get('email')

    if not profile.gender and response.get('gender'):
        profile.gender = response.get('gender')

    if not profile.date_of_birth and response.get('birthday'):
        datestring = response.get('birthday')
        date_format = "%m/%d/%Y"
        profile.date_of_birth = datetime.strptime(datestring, date_format)

    profile.user = user
    profile.save()
    user.save()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if backend.__class__.__name__ == 'FacebookBackend':
```